# JS and PHP scripts don't load in Chrome or IE8

Tags: php, javascript, frontpage-extensions

JS and PHP scripts don't load properly under Chrome or IE. I am using FrontPage 2003 (SP-3) to develop a home business website in support of video game development.

```
<?PHP
if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false) {
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"register.js\"");

 } else {
      header("Content-type: text/force-download");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"register.js\"");

 } else {
 <Location register.js>
      ForceType ('application/x-httpd-php')
</Location>
}

require_once("./include/membersite_config.js");


if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->RegisterUser())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("thank-you.html");
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Step 1: Don't use FrontPage.

Comment: Your code contains painfully obvious syntax errors. PHP will tell you exactly where they appear. Please try to fix the simple things before posting new questions to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
} else {
 <Location register.js>
      ForceType ('application/x-httpd-php')
</Location>
}
```

That is not valid PHP...(And you will do really well to listen to AlienWebguy's advice)

Comment: That doesnt look like valid JS either. It looks a set of server directives if you ask me. At any rate if you need to have that in PHP, you should do it so:
`echo "<Location register.js>
      ForceType ('application/x-httpd-php')
</Location>";`. While syntactically correct, I am not sure what that will achieve because like I said, it neither looks valid PHP nor valid JS..